# understanding the output of a function

Tags: r, mapply

Trying to understand how the value of "traded" is 34

```
available <- c(10,4,7,10,12)
desired <- c(12,5,2,6,14)
traded <- sum(mapply(function(x,y) min(x,y), available, desired))
```

Correct value for traded is 34. Just not sure why this is the case. I thought the value would be 6 as the minimum values from each vector (4 and 2) summed together =6

Comment: takes the _pairwise_ min for the vectors and sums them, same as `sum(pmin(available, desired))`

Comment: @rawr Thanks for the reply. I have edited my question as I think I worded it badly. Im looking to understand why the value of "traded" is 34

Comment: Why is easy:  10+4+2+6+12. mapply applies min(x,y) to get the min of available/desired at each of the 6 pairs from min(available[1],desired[1]) to min(available[6],desired[6]). mapply applies multiple arguments to each item in turn from  lists/frames/etc.

Answer (score 2):

---

This is answered in the comments, but I wanted to add this breakdown since it helps me to visualize each step.

1. **mapply(function(x,y) min(x,y))**: Maps min(x,y) to each item in vectors x and y , so the function is doing this:

   ```
   min(10,12)

   min(4,5)

   min(7,2)

   min(10,6)

   min(12,14)
   ```

   and outputs = (10, 4, 2, 6, 12)

2. **sum(mapply(...))**: Which "sees" the output above and computes 10+4+2+6+12 = 34